# How to convert Spark's TableRDD to RDD[Array[Double]] in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shark-sql

I am trying to perform `Scala` operation on [Shark](http://shark.cs.berkeley.edu/). I am creating an RDD as follows:

```
val tmp: shark.api.TableRDD = sc.sql2rdd("select duration from test")
```

I need it to convert it to `RDD[Array[Double]]`. I tried `toArray`, but it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried converting it to `Array[String]` and then converting using `map` as follows:

```
val tmp_2 = tmp.map(row => row.getString(0))
val tmp_3 = tmp_2.map { row => 
  val features = Array[Double] (row(0))
}
```

But this gives me a Spark's `RDD[Unit]` which cannot be used in the function. Is there any other way to proceed with this type conversion?

**Edit** I also tried using `toDouble`, but this gives me an `RDD[Double]` type, not `RDD[Array[Double]]`

```
val tmp_5 = tmp_2.map(_.toDouble)
```

**Edit 2:**

I managed to do this as follows:

A sample of the data:

```
296.98567000000003
230.84362999999999
212.89751000000001
914.02404000000001
305.55383
```

A Spark Table RDD was created first.

```
val tmp = sc.sql2rdd("select duration from test")
```

I made use of `getString` to translate it to a `RDD[String]` and then converted it to an `RDD[Array[Double]]`.

```
val duration = tmp.map(row => Array[Double](row.getString(0).toDouble))
```

Comment: I assume your query `select duration from test` is returning only the `duration` column. Do you want to convert each single entry into an array or do you want to convert the result set into an array?  In the second case, why would you still want that single array as an RDD?

Comment: @maasg I would like to convert each entry from the result (i.e.duration column values) into an array. I'm using an existing function and it needs the input datatype to be RDD[Array[Double]]

Comment: adding some sample data would help, I think.

Comment: @maasg I have edited the question to add an approach which works for now.